# Selenium Testing Keypress to test a type ahead result

Tags: c#, testing, selenium

I want to test that if the suggestion box shows when the user types in the textbox. How can I make selenium type the text in the box instead of pasting it which does not trigger the suggestion box to show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use sendKeys method. Read more [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#sendKeys-java.lang.CharSequence...-) about it.

Comment: Turns out I was putting complete suggestion keyword in the TextBox which never gave the chance to the autocomplete to popup. I changed it to only send a single character and then the autocomplete shows up.